# How to perform matrix matrix division using eigen library in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen3

I did a `MATLAB` code and it had to perform

```
B3=abs(B2/max(B2));
```

where `B2` is an `181 x 238` matrix , `max(B2)` should give me a matrix of `1 x 238` comprising of maximum value in each column and `B3` should be `181x1`matrix. What should be the equivalent `C++` code using Eigen library? Please help.
On modifying my code, with simpler dimension say with 2 x 2 matrix

```
//problem
#include <iostream>
#include<complex.h>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd A(2,2);MatrixXd B(2,1);MatrixXd C(1,2);
    A<<4,12,
       6,8;
            C=A.colwise().maxCoeff();
        //B=(A*(1.0/C)).cwiseAbs();
             B=A.array()/C.array();
   cout << "The solution is A :\n" << B.cwiseAbs()<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I am not able to execute this code.

hp@hp-HP-Notebook:~/beamforming/programs/eigen_prog$ g++ mm_t.cpp -o mm_t

hp@hp-HP-Notebook:~/beamforming/programs/eigen_prog$ ./mm_t
mm_t: /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseBinaryOp.h:110: Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp::CwiseBinaryOp(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const BinaryOp&) [with BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op; LhsType = const Eigen::ArrayWrapper >; RhsType = const Eigen::ArrayWrapper >; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp::Lhs = Eigen::ArrayWrapper >; Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp::Rhs = Eigen::ArrayWrapper >]: Assertion `aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Any idea what is wrong?? 
I did simple execution in my MATLAB command window to simplify what I want to get as output.

> > m=[4,12;6,8]

m =

```
 4    12
 6     8
```

> > max(m)

ans =
     6  12

> > abs(m/max(m))

ans =

```
0.9333
0.7333
```

> > 

I am stuck with this problem for a long time. Please help.

Comment: maxCoeff() returns the largest element in the whole matrix. But in MATLAB max(A) , where A is matrix, should give  row vector containing the maximum value of each column. I have made changes describing my problem more clearly indicating my matrix dimensions

Comment: `A * C.asDiagonal().inverse()` ? Actually, I don't know what your `abs` means, so this is just a random suggestion, probably wrong.

Comment: Y = abs( X ) returns the absolute value of each element in array X . If X is complex, abs(X) returns the complex magnitude.No, this still results in a 2 x 2 matrix  

0.666667        1
       1 0.666667

Comment: Then it is your division that is confusing, you really should explain what each operation means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret `B3=abs(B2/max(B2))` as folllowing.

- `b = max(B2)` is a row vector containing the largest elements of the respective columns of `B2`.
- `q = B2/b` means the least-squares solution to the overdetermined linear equations `q b = B2`. (There are `nrow` independent problems, where `nrow` is the number of rows of `B2`). This equation is equivalent to `b^T q^T = B2^T`, where `^T` is my notation for transpose, and this form is more frequently implemented in many libraries, I guess.
- `abs(q)` means the elementwise absolute value of `q`.

So, the required result is `x` below. Maybe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd A(2,2), Atr(2,2);
  VectorXd b(2), x(2);
  A<<4,12,
    6,8;
  cout << "A :\n" << A << endl;

  Atr=A.transpose();
  cout << "Atr :\n" << Atr << endl;

  b=A.colwise().maxCoeff();
  cout << "b :\n" << b << endl;

  x = b.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(Atr).cwiseAbs();
  cout << "x :\n" << x << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
A :
 4 12
 6  8
Atr :
 4  6
12  8
b :
 6
12
x :
0.933333
0.733333
```

cf.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html

---

- Below is my old answer based on misunderstanding of the definition of `A/v` in Matlab.

Maybe the result `B3` in the quection corresponds to the vector `x` below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd A(2,2);
  VectorXd b(2), x(2);
  A<<4,12,
    6,8;
  cout << "A :\n" << A << endl;

  b=A.colwise().maxCoeff();
  cout << "b :\n" << b << endl;

  x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b).cwiseAbs();
  cout << "x :\n" << x << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

cf

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

---

*Below is old and wrong answer based on my misunderstanding of `max(A)` in matlab.*

In Matlab, `max(A)` is the maximum element of the matrix `A`, and `abs(A)` returns a matrix taking the absolute values of the respective element of `A`. 
So, if `B2` is a Matrix object of eigen, maybe

```
B2=(B2*(1.0/B2.maxCoeff())).cwiseAbs()
```

cf. 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html?searchHighlight=abs&s_tid=gn_loc_drop
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html

Comment: Thank you . But M = max( A ) returns the largest elements of A . If A is a vector, then max(A) returns the largest element of A . If A is a matrix, then max(A) is a row vector containing the maximum value of each column. maxCoeff() returns only maximum element of the matrix. So how to modify the  above code??

Comment: You are right. I was wrong about `max(A)` in the case of `A` being matrix. Then, how  is`A/v` defined for matrix `A` and vector `v` in Matlab?

Comment: Ah, O.K. `A/v` means the solution `x` to `A x = v`.

Comment: Ah, `A/v` is actually `x` such that `x A = v` (not `A x = v`). My answer is still wrong.

Comment: Oh, no. `A/v` actually means the least square solution `x` to `x v = A`. It's peculiar, but anyways my answer is still wrong.

Comment: I tried to do this with colPivHouseholderQr() , but the answer I got differs from that of MATLAB. This is the site [Eigen ](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can this code be used in the case of complex double matrices too??

Comment: I used MatrixXcd and VectorXcd instead , but it results in error

Comment: I'm not sure about the case of complex double case, but you can examine the definition of each of the functions called in the documentation. The  `colPivHouseholderQr` may be unstable for some matrix (well, actually a vector) `b`. Also think whether or not you should replace `A.transpose()` with a complex conjugated transpose.  I confess here that it's my first time to use Eigen, and that I stopped using Matlab about 6 years ago. I answered by reading documents of Eigen and Matlab after you posted your question. So, I hope you can also go further and help yourself by reading documents more!